# Can such an "orthogonal" matrix exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I know that the definition of an orthogonal matrix is that $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is orthogonal if $AA^T = A^T A=I$, no problem with that whatsoever.

My question is this - Why only square matrices?

Is it possible that there is a matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$ such that $AA^T =I_n$ and $A^TA= I_k$?

if so - could you find an example? and if not - why not?

This is not for homework, this is merely my curiosity

Comment: Think about the rank of the matrix and what that means in terms of the dimension of the image.

Comment: If $n<k$ it is possible to have $A A^T=I_n$, and if $n>k$ it is possible to have $A^T A=I_k$. But it is impossible to have both unless $n=k$. Mark Bennet's comment suggests how to see this. (Incidentally, this is important: these "half-orthogonal" matrices are used in the reduced QR decomposition.)

Comment: Got it. if $AA^T = I_n$ then $A$ has rank $n$ at least, and if $A^TA=I_k$ then $A^T$ has rank $k$ at least. Since $rank(A)=rank(A^T)$ that means $A$ has rank at least $k$ and at least $n$, so they must be equal.

Comment: You can post that as an answer, Oria. It is encouraged to post answers to your own questions, if a discussion has shown you how to do them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. if $AA^T=I_n$ then $A$ has rank $n$ at least, and if $A^TA=I_k$ then $A^T$ has rank $k$ at least. Since $rank(A)=rank(A^T)$ that means $A$ has rank at least $k$ and at least $n$, so they must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

You've already answered your question correctly with "no". However, the concept of orthogonal matrices can be somewhat generalized to non-square matrices. An $n \times k$ matrix $A$ is called *semi-orthogonal* if $A^TA$ or $AA^T$ is the identity matrix.

Another characterization of this property is that $A$ has no singular values other than $0$ or $1$.